# system("killall SpringBoard"); not working in ios4.2.1?

Tags: iphone, system, ios-4.2, iphone-3gs

So I had created an app that used the command system("killall SpringBoard"); and it has worked just fine on 4.0 - 4.1. I just recently began testing the app on 4.2 and it still works when I run it in simulator, but when I run it on the device nothing happens. Does anyone know what the cause of this is? The device is a iPhone 3GS.

Comment: I'd be surprised if `system()` were even allowed on non-jailbroken iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. It's an app that I'm using on my own device which I have no interest in pursuing release in the app store/non-jailbroken iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restart SpringBoard cleanly, please use

```
notify_post("com.apple.language.changed");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working (anymore). I have a 4.3.3 iPhone 4, and while calling notify_post("com.apple.language.changed") does not cause a visual respringing, where the screen locks afterwards, it also does not cause SpringBoard to reload its settings. Using 'ps' at the command line also shows the same process ID. So, basically, this isn't restarting SpringBoard is any sense. Any ideas?